# Calculate angles in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

If we have a set of points `Rs`, we can use torch.cdist to get the **all** pair distances.

```
dists_ij = torch.cdist(Rs, Rs)
```

Is there a function to get the angles between two set of vectors `Vs` like this:

```
angs_ij = torch.angs(Vs, Vs)
```

Comment: maybe this one: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.angle.html

Comment: That one is about angle in complex numbers, not between vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this manually using the [relation between the dot product of two vectors and the angle between them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#/media/File:Inner-product-angle.svg):

```py
# normalize the vectors
nVs = Vs / torch.norm(Vs, p=2, dim=-1, keepdim=True)
# compute cosine of the angles using dot product
cos_ij = torch.einsum('bni,bmi->bnm', nVs, nVs)
```